# Ableton 9.5 -- custom Simpler slice markers?

Tags: ableton-live

The sensitivity knob adds slice markers automatically

I see that double clicking adds grey slice markers, and that I can drag the grey slice markers.

How do I create orange slice markers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac OSX:

1. Set sensitivity to 100
2. Remove unwanted slice markers (right click `->` clear slices, or double click)
3. `Option` + `Click` on a grey transient / start marker

Comment: you can check "answered question" for your own answers. Best.